# how to render smothly P5.js in hdpi screen?

Tags: javascript, processing, render, p5.js, hdpi

Computer with hdpi screen are more and more common and I own one.
I'm building a webpage with a P5.js canvas inside it filling a div. 
I have absolutely no problem till this point, but as I have an hdpi screen the number of pixels to render is tremendous and it's very hard to render smoothly.

what I would like to do: render a low-resolution canvas an stretching it to fill all the space.  But I have no ideé how to achieve this or even if it's possible.

```js
function setup() {
    var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var divWidth = canvasDiv.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    var divHeight = canvasDiv.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    var sketchCanvas = createCanvas(divWidth,divHeight);
    sketchCanvas.parent("myCanvas");

    background(0)

   
}
function windowResized() {
   var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var divWidth = canvasDiv.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    var divHeight = canvasDiv.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    resizeCanvas(divWidth, divHeight);

     background(0)
}



function draw(){
 
  
 
}
```

Comment: Stretching a canvas is easy. `<canvas width="200" height="200 style="width:400px;height:400px">` i.e. jut use CSS to stretch it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step one:** Create an off-screen buffer using the `createGraphics()` function. More info can be found in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createGraphics). Give it whatever low-res size you want.

**Step two:** Draw your scene to that off-screen buffer. Use its width and height to draw stuff to scale.

**Step three:** Draw the off-screen buffer to the screen, using the `image()` function, which takes parameters for the size to draw. Use the size of the canvas as the arguments. Again, more info can be found in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/image).

You'll still be drawing the same amount of pixels, but that's how you'd draw to a small buffer and resize it to match the canvas size.

If you're still having trouble, please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a new question post, and we'll go from there. Good luck.